# Blazor Server App generates different connection Id when I start components that use SignalR

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr

I'm using Blazor server App in my project. I use the following codes in the `main layout` and in `every component` needs to send or receive message from SignalR:

```
private HubConnection? notificationHubConnection;

public bool IsConnected =>
notificationHubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    if (notificationHubConnection is not null)
    {
        await notificationHubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    notificationHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/ServerHub"))
        .Build();

    await notificationHubConnection.StartAsync();
}
```

When I open the web application a `connectionId` is generated by default. When I use each component a new `connectionId` is generated. Is it normal? How can I fix this?

Comment: It is normal since they are different object instances. You should add a singleton or a top level component that hold the connection

Comment: @sasal If I start connection on top level component, how can I access hub connection on other components? Can you write a simple example please?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using SignalR in a Blazor Server project when it already uses SignalR - genuine interest in your choice - not a snark :)

Comment: @MisterMagoo I use it for send notifications in different parts of my app. It is also used for Realtime messaging.